# Trouble recursively building a binary decision tree python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I'm trying to recursively build a binary decision tree, for diagnosing diseases in python 3. 
The builder takes a list of records (each is an illness and a list of its symptoms), and a list of symptoms, shown bellow:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data = "", pos = None, neg = None):
        self.data = data
        self.positive_child = pos
        self.negative_child = neg
class Record:
    def __init__(self, illness, symptoms):
        self.illness = illness
        self.symptoms = symptoms

records= [Record('A',['1','3']),
          Record('B',['1','2']),
          Record('C',['2','3']),
          ]
symptoms = ['1','2','3']
```

And builds a binary tree, each level checks if symptom is true, or false, with a child node for each one. The right child is always means the symtom is not present and the left one that it is present. For the example data the tree should look like this:

```
                       1
               2                    2
          3        3          3            3
    None   B     A   None   C  None   None     Healthy
```

For example, the leaf A is reached by asking:
1 : True
2 : False
3 : True
and it's path is [1,3] (the trues)

Here is the code I'm using, but isn't working:

```
def builder(records, symptoms, path):
    #Chekl if we are in a leaf node that matches an illness
    for record in records:
        if path == record.symptoms:
            return Node(record.illness,None,None)

     #No more symptoms means an empty leaf node
    if len(symptoms) == 0:
        return Node(None,None,None)

    #create subtree
    else:
        symptom = symptoms.pop(0)
        right_child = builder(records,symptoms,path)
        path.append(symptom)
        left_child = builder(records,symptoms,path)
        return  Node(symptom,right_child,left_child)
```

I tried a cold run, and in paper it worked fine. I'm not sure of what I'm missing, but the resulting tree has a lot of empty nodes, and not one with the illness. Maybe I'm messing up the path thing, but I'm not sure how to fix it right now.

Comment: "it isn't working' isn't really precise. What does not work the way you wanted? If I print print(builder(records,symptoms,['1','3']).data) as you described I'm getting A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `symptoms.pop(0)` is affecting the *one* `symptoms` list shared by all calls to `builder`.  This is fine on the way down, since you want to consider only the subsequent symptoms.  But when a recursive call returns, your list is missing elements.  (If it returns without finding a match, it’s empty!)  Similarly, the shared `path` keeps growing forever.

The simple if inefficient answer is to make new lists when recursing:

```
symptom=symptoms[0]
symptoms=symptoms[1:]
path=path+[symptom]  # not +=
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that. Is it possible the same is happening to the path argument? I just did a run with your change and the path is kinda messed up, at some points being longer than the level of the tree.

Comment: I just printed the tree, using a simple recursive function. this was the result:
___ empty
__ 3
___ empty
_ 2
___ empty
__ 3
___ empty
 1
___ empty
__ 3
___ empty
_ 2
___ empty
__ 3
___ empty

Which means the tree was correctly constructed, but none of the illness leafs were attached. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I tried "left_child = builder(records,symptoms[1:],path.append(symptom))"
but I got an error that states that "None Object type has no atribute append"

Comment: @Silver: `list.append` returns `None` (and not a list) precisely so you _don’t_ think it makes a new list that you can use this way.

Comment: @Silver: I edited the answer (to include the `path` issue you raised) in a way that obviates the need to change the recursive calls at all.

Comment: Davis thanks a lot. I'll admit that Im not used to recursion, and I didn't knew that pop() and append() affected a list shared by all the calls and was having a hard time finding the mistake,